# Looking for files that already exist based off patterns/regex/substring in Julia

Tags: julia, file-handling

I want to see if some files already exist, but a-priori I only part of the file name, namely the path and the file-type (the full name depends on some data inside the file).

I thought I could do something like

```
prop_val = Regex(joinpath(base_name,"*.csv"))
isfile(prop_val)
```

but this returns the error

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching joinpath(::Regex)
Closest candidates are:
  joinpath(::AbstractString) at path.jl:251
  joinpath(::AbstractString, ::AbstractString...) at path.jl:296
```

I guess this makes sense if objects of type `regex` aren't subtypes of `AbstractString`.

Is there a better way of doing this rather than, for example

```
for file in readdir(base_name)
    if occursin(".csv",file)
        # do something
    end
end
```

Comment: https://juliapackages.com/p/glob

Comment: This has nothing to do with regex (please remove `regex` label). `*.csv` is glob, not regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shorter version of the latter code in your question:

```
filter(endswith(".csv"), readdir(base_name))
```

For eg., if your goal is to just check if such a file exists,

```
if filter(endswith(".csv"), readdir(base_name)) |> length > 0
  # do stuff
end
```